# Keeping sessionalive between 2 WS calls

Tags: java, web-services, playframework

I would like to know if it is possible to keep the sessions created after a first ws call to use it for a second one ?

I explain myself a little more : I got a ws call made for my authentification, if my authentification works i'll store a variable. At my second call the security module for Play! will check if this variable is set , if it is it performs the action else it responds with an UNAUTHORIZED http response.

For now i only get the unauthorize response.

Is there any way to keep this session alive and linked to this 2 calls ?

Comment: The session in Play is stored in a Cookie in the requester's browser and should therefore be the same in subsequent calls (unless you change it). You can read about it in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash.

Comment: thanks that helped :)